# Как вставить текст после определенного слова в string?

Tags: ios, swift

Есть переменная типа `string` в ней `html` код

```
var htmlString = "<img alt=\"\" src=\"/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/swift-big.jpg" style=\"height:326px; margin:10px; width:563px\" />"
```

Суть в том что перед `"/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/swift-big.jpg"` мне нужно вставить `https://www.iphones.ru`, то есть после `src=\"`
Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учитывая что вы работаете с Wordpress и явно решаете локальную задачу (не универсальную), самый простой вариант это использовать замену:

```
var htmlString = "<img alt=\"\" src=\"/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/swift-big.jpg\" style=\"height:326px; margin:10px; width:563px\" />"
let domain = "https://www.iphones.ru"
let textForFind = "src=\"/wp-content/uploads/"
let textForReplace = "src=\"\(domain)/wp-content/uploads/"
htmlString = htmlString.replacingOccurrences(of: textForFind, with: textForReplace)
print(htmlString)
```

Если задача сделать более универсальный код, можно искать src=\" с помощью let range = htmlString.range(of: "src=\""), затем вырезать текст до и после src=\" и добавлять домен при склеивании.